Did Jesus ever claim to be God?
Where did Jesus claim to be God? I can't find this statement in the Bible. The question "What did Jesus likely say in John 8:58?" does not help. Jesus did not use the Tetragrammaton which leads me to believe he was saying he existed before Abraham or even that YHWH existed before Abraham. Clearing he is telling the Jews that had forgotten about their father God.

This question is similar to: What did Jesus likely say in John 8:58?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

John the Baptist and Paul and Peter all attest to Jesus Christ being 'the Son of God'. The question must, itself, prove that the term 'Son of God' does not, of itself, mean that the Son is of the same nature as the Father. Without such an explanation the question becomes a mere text-search which, even if it is negative, is regarded as being off-topic on this particular site.

Please take some main scriptures to prove your answer Biblically with care to follow the basic principles of hermeneutics. Your answer here seems rather off the cuff and less detailed and clearly explained as it should be, considering the weight of the question in the context of such a widely known view held by most Biblical followers of Jesus Christ. Some possible guidance - https://www.biblestudytools.com/topical-verses/jesus-is-lord-bible-verses/

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Exodus reads, “God replied to Moses, “I AM WHO I AM" Exodus 3:14.  The text in John 8:58 is "I am" small "am" not "Am" as stated in Exodus. This is clearly a different statement. In John 8:39-41 we read, "If you were Abraham’s children,” Jesus told them, “you would do what Abraham did. But now you are trying to kill Me, (a man) who has told you the truth that I heard from God. Abraham did not do this! You’re doing what your father does.” Jesus clearly tells them he is a man and is saying what God told him to say.

@RomanDeLeon Here's a more important question. Why did the Sanhedrin along with the Pharisees sentence Jesus with blasphemy and then execute him? Even Jesus had a mission to keep the truth from the Jews about him. Yet they all still understood what He was claiming in a round about way. When Jesus has his trial with the Sanhedrin, he confirms being the "son of man" and that's all they needed. Why can they who were blinded see it, but you can't? Or are you looking for a literal phrase like "I am God"? Is that the only way to say that someone is God? If so, you have locked yourself in a box.

@Biff Jesus clearly is the Son of God in my box, he is not the Most High. In John 14 Jesus says, “Your heart must not be troubled. Believe in (God); believe also in (Me). In Matthew we read, "And there came a voice from heaven: This is My beloved Son. God called him, His son. (Matthew 3:17 ) We have to read our bibles and not take for granted what we were taught. Read, (John 19:7) "We have a law,” the Jews replied to him, “and according to that law He must die, because He made Himself the Son of God.” Why did they kill Jesus? Jesus NEVER identifies himself as being the Most High.

@Roman De Leon You are mistaken. He clearly called Himself JHVH after the resurrection.

18 Then Jesus came to them and said, “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to Me.
19 Therefore go and make disciples of all nations, baptizing them in the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of the Holy Spirit,
20 and teaching them to obey all that I have commanded you. And surely I am with you always, even to the end of the age.” (Matthew 28)

7 Then Moses called for Joshua and said to him in the presence of all Israel, “Be strong and courageous, for you will go with this people into the land that the LORD swore to their fathers to give them, and you shall give it to them as an inheritance.
8 The LORD Himself goes before you; He will be with you. He will never leave you nor forsake you. Do not be afraid or discouraged.” (Deuteronomy 31)

@ארקדיוס This will be my last comment and I hope this would lead those reading to study the Bible and words of Jesus more often. Matthew 11:25-27 reads, "At that time Jesus said, “I praise You, (Father), (Lord of heaven and earth), because You have hidden these things from the wise and learned and revealed them to infants. Yes, Father, because this was Your good pleasure. All things have been entrusted to Me by My Father. No one knows the Son except the Father, and no one knows the Father except the Son and anyone to whom the Son desires to reveal Him." Who is Jesus praying to? שָׁלוֹם

@Roman De Leon I quoted you Jesus saying He is God. Jesus had to fulfil the role of the servant to save the humanity. He did it by dying and then rose from the grave. He is not the servant any more. Now, he is the king of the universe. The Son of Man and the Ancient of Days in one package, as in Rev.1:13-15.  Don't try to dodge it with a verse from before the crucifixion.

@ארקדיוס  Yeshua tells me to, love the Lord my God with all your heart, with all my soul, and with all my mind and to love my neighbor as myself." So I will obey his commands because He sits at the right hand of His Father and my Father.

@ארקדיוס Rev. 11:15, "The kingdom of the world has become the kingdom
of our (Lord) and of (His Messiah), and He will reign forever and ever!"

@RomanDeLeon Not so fast. Jesus claimed He was of the Father and one with the Father. 1Jn 1:1 - "this we proclaim concerning the Word of life. 2 The life appeared; we have seen it and testify to it, and we proclaim to you the eternal life, which was with the Father and has appeared to us". The live word identified as 'Logos' meaning God's wisdom, reason, logic, authority was born as flesh. The flesh with sinful nature was successfully suppressed, enduring temptation to the point of  death. You cannot remove the Logos from the Father because it belongs to Him.

@Biff I really like your theory! We have to understand that John's audience were Greeks. He is using philosophical terms to better help them understand. Everyone has used their own theology here, but I have only shared the very words uttered by Jesus with direct statements from Him.  John 10:35-36 says "If he called them gods to whom the word (logos) of God came—and Scripture cannot be broken do you say of (him) whom the (Father) consecrated and sent (Jesus) into the world, ‘You are blaspheming,’ because I (Jesus) said, ‘I am the Son(Jesus) of God (YHWH)’?

@RomanDeLeon unfortunately, this is a trinitarian site and such questions are not appreciated. Jesus never claimed to be God, in fact his God is the same God we have, so he simply cannot be the God of himself. He plainly declared the Father is the only true God, but not many believe him.

@Steve- I am sorry you were offended. I you read your bible Jesus called us to make disciples, not trinitarians or christians. Maybe I should remove myself from your site. I am not posting a question, nor commenting to prove anyone wrong. I am always sharing scripture references to bring insight to the reader. This question was closed, why comment?

@ארקדיוס - “All authority in heaven and on earth has been given to Me - that by it self is sufficient to imply there is someone more superior - God cant give God authority

@ארקדיוס- If your statement stands correct. Then you are right God cant give God authority because he would have already had the authority. But God gave His Son the authority. Let not your heart be troubled: ye believe in God, believe also in me.

This question will be correctly closed shortly.  However, in the spirit of helpfulness, here are some occasions when Jesus effectively claimed to be  either Messiah, The Son of God, and the “I Am” of the OT (see LXX Deut 32:39, Isa 41:4, 43:10, 13, 25, 45:19, 46:4, 48:12, 51:12, 52:6), and thus, God in the fullest sense.
1.    Woman at the well

John 4:25, 26 - The woman said, “I know that Messiah” (called Christ)
“is coming. When He comes, He will explain everything to us.” Jesus
answered, “The one speaking to you, I Am.”

This “I Am” declaration serves a dual function:

to positively identify Himself as Messiah
to affirm that Jesus is the “I Am” of the OT (see above OT references).

Thus, in the incident recorded in John 4, Jesus is introduced as a man who is tired and hungry (V6), but who is actually, God.
2.    Jesus Heals a Paralytic Matt 9:1-8, Mark 2:1-12, Luke 5:17-26
In the healing of a paralytic at Capernaum, Jesus used His power to forgive sins as direct evidence of His divinity.  First, he declares, without the paralytic asking, that his sins were forgiven.  He was then accused of blasphemy because He forgave sins.  Then Jesus makes the famous statement to prove His divinity –

Mark 2:8-11 - At once Jesus knew in His spirit that they were thinking
this way within themselves. “Why are you thinking these things in your
hearts?” He asked.  “Which is easier: to say to a paralytic, ‘Your
sins are forgiven,’ or to say, ‘Get up, pick up your mat, and walk’?
But so that you may know that the Son of Man has authority on earth to
forgive sins...” He said to the paralytic, “I tell you, get up, pick
up your mat, and go home.”

3.    John 5 - Healing at the Pool of Bethesda
The healing of the man at the pool of Bethesda followed by an extended discussion between the Jews and Jesus in John 5 is a special event where Jesus makes repeated claims about His divinity and equality with the Father; thus, it deserves special attention.
[NOTE: Jesus performed seven miracles on the Sabbath: Mark 1:21-28, 29-31, 3:1-6, John 9:1-16, Luke 13:10-17, 14:1-6, John 5:1-18. In several of these, Jesus was accused of breaking the Sabbath and had to defend His actions. The differences in His defence are significant. In Mark 3:1-6, John 9:1-16, Luke 13:10-17, Jesus defends His actions on the Sabbath by essentially claiming He was doing good, etc.]
However, in John 5:1-18, Jesus heals the man at Bethesda on Sabbath. In this case, Jesus made no attempt to defend Himself by claiming that He was doing good etc. Rather He claimed that this was part of His regular job of working continuously just as the Father does (compare Col 1:17) and thus was not guilty of Sabbath breaking.
This is significant; Jesus’ defense in John 5 was essentially His divinity as He states several times in the subsequent discussion in John 5.  Thus, Jesus' defense is unique here - He claims equality with the Father and the need to uphold the universe (Col 1:17), and thus, was not guilty of breaking the Sabbath.
The great problem that the Jews had in John 5, against which Jesus defends Himself, appears to have at least two facets:

God (as they understood Him) is Almighty, Grand, Majestic and distant (despite the above). It was precisely this idea that the Gospel of John was written to dispel because in its opening prologue, we read: (John 1:18) - No one has ever seen God, but the one and only God, the One being in the bosom of the Father, has made Him known. Compare v1 where the Word is God.
Jesus calls God the Father, “my Father” (V17), ie, His personal Father making Jesus equal with God. [I pause to note, and am surprised to observe that the Jews did not object to this on the basis of strict monotheism!!] This was acknowledged and unchallenged.

Jesus then goes on to say specifically in what aspects He was equal with the Father:

V17 - Both the Father and Jesus must “work” continuously (See Col 1:17) [Ellicott observes: This was familiar to the thought of the day. Comp., e.g., in the contemporary Philo, “God never ceases working; but as to burn is the property of fire, and to be cold is the property of snow, thus also to work is the property of God, and much the more, inasmuch as He is the origin of action for all others” (Legis Allegor. i. 3. See the whole section. The English reader will find it in Bohn’s Ed., vol i., p. 53).]
V17, 18 - Jesus claims the Father as his own personal Father
V19 - The Father and Jesus work together in complete unity (not unison)
V21, 26 - The Father and Jesus both have life in Themselves and can raise people from the dead at will
V22 - The Father has committed all judgement to the Son
V23 - All must honor the Son as they honor the Father
V24, 25 - Jesus' “word” is the key to eternal life

Jesus then summons legal evidence that His testimony about Himself (as outlined above) is valid under Jewish law because:

V31-38 - He has a second, very weighty, witness in His Father.
V39, 40 - Jesus claims to be the fulfillment of the Scriptures as Messiah
V41-47 - Jesus comes in the Name of the Father and they do not believe
Jesus; this, despite the fact that they believe other people who come in their own name.

4.    John 8, Multiple Claims
John 8 is also significant because there are multiple claims made by Jesus:

V12 – “I am the Light of the world” (Compare John 1:9, 9:5) - a direct allusion to Ps 27:1, “The LORD is my light and my salvation”, and, Micah 7:8 “the LORD will be my light.”
V23, 24 - Then He told them, “You are from below; I am from above. You are of this world; I am not of this world. That is why I told you that you would die in your sins. For unless you believe that I am, you will die in your sins.”
V28 - So Jesus said, “When you have lifted up the Son of Man, then you will know that I am, and that I do nothing on My own, but speak exactly what the Father has taught Me.
V58, 59 - “Truly, truly, I tell you,” Jesus declared, “before Abraham was born, I am!” At this, they picked up stones to throw at Him. ...
Thus, Jesus makes a triple claim to be the great “I AM” of the OT in this chapter.  Further, Jesus’ claim about being the “I Am” of the OT is couched in three ways: In the past (V58), in the present (V24), and in the future (V28). That is, Jesus always was, is, and always will be the great “I Am”.  Compare the same title of God in Rev 1:8 - “I am the Alpha and the Omega,” says the Lord God, “who is, and who was, and who is to come, the Almighty.”

5.    John 10 – the Good Shepherd

V11, 14, 15 “I am the good Shepherd … I am the good Shepherd … there will be one flock and One Shepherd.” (Compare Ps 23:1, “The LORD is my Shepherd”.)
V24-27, So the Jews gathered around Him and demanded, “How long will You keep us in suspense? If You are the Christ, tell us plainly.” “I already told you,” Jesus replied, “but you did not believe.  The works I do in My Father’s name testify on My behalf.  But because you are not My sheep, you refuse to believe.  My sheep listen to My voice; I know them, and they follow Me. (Compare 1 Peter 5:4.)
V30, 31, 33, “I and the Father are one.” At this, the Jews again picked up stones to stone Him. ... “We are not stoning You for any good work,” said the Jews, “but for blasphemy, because You, who are a man, declare Yourself to be God.”

This claim that “I and the Father are one” appears to be an allusion to the famous “Shema” of Deut 6:4, “Hear, O Israel, the LORD our God, the LORD is One”.  This explains the Jews’ accusation about a man claiming to be God as blasphemous.
6.    Peter's Confession

Matt 16:16, 17 - Simon Peter answered, “You are the Christ, the Son of
the living God.” Jesus replied, “Blessed are you, Simon son of Jonah!
For this was not revealed to you by flesh and blood, but by My Father
in heaven."

Note the dual title of (1) Christ/Messiah, and, (2) The Son of God
7.    Trial before the Sanhedrin

Mark 14:61-64 - Again the high priest questioned Him, “Are You the
Christ, the Son of the Blessed One?” “I am” said Jesus, “and you will
see the Son of Man sitting at the right hand of Power and coming with
the clouds of heaven.” At this, the high priest tore his clothes and
declared, “Why do we need any more witnesses? You have heard the
blasphemy. What is your verdict?” And they all condemned Him as
deserving of death.

In this instance, Jesus effectively claims several things, namely:

That He was the Christ/Messiah
That He was The Son of God
That He was The “I Am”
That He was The Son of Man
That He was the legitimate King of Israel, both literal and spiritual
… and thus, that He was both fully human and fully divine

Note that claiming to be a human messiah was nothing new. However, explicitly claiming to be both human (the Son of Man) and divine (the Son of God) and Messiah all at once, was (to them) quote blasphemous; but only if it was not true!  This was confirmed by the High Priest illegally tearing is robes as a symbol of his horror of blasphemy.
8.    Arrest in the Garden
John 18 records the arrest of Jesus in the Garden and the exchange between Him and the mob:

4 Jesus, knowing all that was coming upon Him, stepped forward and
asked them, “Whom are you seeking?”
5 “Jesus of Nazareth,” they answered. Jesus said, “I am.”
And Judas His betrayer was standing there with them. 6 When Jesus
said, “I am,” they drew back and fell to the ground.
7 So He asked them again, “Whom are you seeking?” “Jesus of Nazareth,”
they answered.
8 “I told you that I am.” Jesus replied.

In this instance, the “I Am” of Jesus clearly serves a dual function:

to positively identify Himself as the Jesus of Nazareth whom they are seeking to arrest
to affirm that Jesus is the “I Am” of the OT, as confirmed by the fact that this declaration of His divinity made the arresting mob fall backwards.

9.    Thomas' Confession

John 20:28 - Thomas said to him, ‘My Lord and my God.’ [literally, The
Lord of me and the God (ho theos) of me].

Jesus then commended Thomas for finally arriving at this conclusion (contrast Acts 10:25, 26, Rev 19:10, 22:8, 9).
10.   Jesus' Questions of Peter
Following Peter’s triple denial of Jesus (John 18:15-18, 25-27), Peter soon realized the enormity of what he had done when Jesus, “turned and looked straight at Peter. … And he went outside and wept bitterly.” (Luke 22:61, 62)  Peter realized that in denying Jesus, he had placed the approval of others above his love for Jesus.
But there was no opportunity for any reconciliation before Jesus’ crucifixion.
However, following Jesus’ resurrection, Jesus met the disciples on the shore of Lake Galilee and Jesus asked three times, “Simon son of John, Do you love Me?” (John 21:15, 16, 17).  Peter, each time, answered affirmatively.  This included the very first question where Jesus askes more specifically, “Simon son of John, Do you love Me more than these?”
This is deeply significant, especially in view of Thomas’ truthful declaration, ‘My Lord and my God’ in the previous incident.  Jesus is essentially asking NOT that Peter love Jesus more than the other disciples loved Jesus, BUT, that Peter love Jesus more than he loves anything else.
There is an unmistakable allusion to the very first and most important commandment:

Deut 6:5 - Love the LORD your God with all your heart and with all
your soul and with all your strength.

Thus, Thomas had just declared Jesus both “Lord” and “God”, and now Jesus is asking Peter to love Him according to the greatest commandment – to love the Lord his God supremely more than anything else; that is, to make Jesus the first & last, best, and most important thing in his life, that is, always at the top of his priority and attention.  Thus, again, Jesus effectively claims to the same God of Deut 6:5.
Indeed, if this were not the case, then Jesus would be asking Peter to break this commandment of Deut 6:5.

Dottard, thank you! But there is not one reference where Jesus calls himself God. You reference John's gospel which was clearly written to help the audience understand that Jesus is the Son of God. "For God loved the world in this way: He gave His One and Only Son" John 3:16 Jesus says in John, “Isn’t it written in your scripture, I said, you are gods? If He called those whom the word of God came to ‘gods’—and the Scripture cannot be broken do you say, ‘You are blaspheming’ to the One the Father set apart and sent into the world, because I said: I am the Son of God? He calls Himself the Son!

@RomanDeLeon - look carefully at what I have written above.  Jesus called Himself the great "I Am" of the OT.

these are verse where Jesus the Son of God, the Messiah in describing himself "I am" not "I Am". We cannot twist the text to make it fit our answer.

A fullsome answer indeed, though if a contentious spirit is shown in response  or elsewhere in this Q, that would indeed further merit the Q being closed down. +1

In Jesus' time, a person who was born and raised as a Jew who claimed to be the unique Son of God and said they were equal with the Father, was saying they were God.
Here is what the Jews said to Pilate:

The Jews answered him, “We have a law, and according to that law he ought to die because he has made himself the Son of God.” (John 19:7 ESV)

There is no mention of a Son of God as Jesus used that title in the Law. The only way the Jews could make the claim using the title deserved the death penalty, is they understood the manner in which Jesus used the title and applied it to Himself, was a claim to be God.
The Gospel clearly states the Jews believed Jesus deserved to die. Why? The language He used and the claims He made about Himself.

Revelation Lad please share where you received this information. In my 20 years of studying I have never heard this. If this was something the Jews were familiar with then why did they want to kill Jesus. John 8:59 says, "At that, they picked up stones to throw at Him."

@RomanDeLeon They wanted to kill Him because what He said was a claim to be God. As to your other remark, I think it is clear that is how the High Priest and Jewish leaders understood His statements. “The Jews answered him, “We have a law, and according to that law he ought to die because he has made himself the Son of God.” (John 19:7)

@rev seriously? Where does Jesus claim to be God and where does he claim equality? You are either content with fabricated theories or massive contradictions - which is it? Does your God have a God as Jesus said he did?

@Steve I have edited the answer. You have to remember, making claims which must be understood in the real-time sense they were made, are not refuted by what you find outside the historical setting they were made. Jesus made several claims which the Jews took to mean He was making Himself God (or equal to God). They tried repeatedly to execute Him for making the claims. They finally succeeded. Pilate stated He was innocent of any wrongdoing; the Jews disagreed. I am simply stating a conclusion from history: Jesus was put to death because the Jews understood He made Himself God.

You can take the side of Pilate and argue the Jews were wrong. But reasons you present do not change the reasons the Jews had and the decision they made.

Yes, exactly, the Jews thought he had a demon! Do you not believe Jesus who declared quite explicitly that the Father was the only true God? This requires no elaborate conjecture about a god/man who only exists in dogma.

@Steve Those Jews presenting their case to Pilate were not those who said He had a demon, obviously. But that has nothing to with how they understood His claims to be God. Even if they were the same group, having a demon does not excuse the claim to be God. The question is did He ever make the claim. The answer is yes.

And yet, your suggested claim stands against the myriad claims that he was not God and indeed had a God, and still does, of course Rev 1:1 among others. So Jesus must be lying or very confused in order for your claim to be valid.

@Steve Some of the the arguments to be made against can be applied to the Father. However, if you understand God from the OT POV, one God with a plural nature, Elohim, you recognize no one can lay claim to being the God and all are God. The dynamic you see as as refuting His deity, placed within the many places where it is clear He is saying He is God is a consequence of Elohim. I picked one because it is undisputed He said He was the Son of God and it is undisputed how it was understood by the Jews. There are other ways too like, I AM...You choose to look for ways to dispute what...

...He said or to nullify how it was understood at the time. I choose to understand both side of what was said and understood. I also don't play "favorites" by interpreting verses which lack "Father" as if God and Father were always completely interchangeable. There are many places where one expects Father and sees God and vice versa. It is only by assuming Son and/or Spirit are not to be included is that possible.
